# Why update method isn't calling?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

I have a problem. When I click to update image on form, update method isn't calling. I see that in my output logs window. Only may update image in first row in my table.

When I updating first row:

> Hibernate: update shoe_goods set description=?, image=?, in_stock=?,
>   name=?, price=?, size=?, web_store_id=? where id=?

When other rows - nothing.

I save my images in db as byte.
This is my method to display images:

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/imageController/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public byte[] getImages(@PathVariable int id)  {
    return shoeGoodsService.getById(id).getImage();
}
```

**JSP:**

```
<img src="/imageController/${goods.id}" alt="Image" />
```

*Code in DAO class:*

```
@Override
public void update(ShoeGoods shoeGoods) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(shoeGoods);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
}
```

*Code in Service class:*

```
@Override
public void update(ShoeGoods shoeGoods) {
    shoeGoodsDAO.update(shoeGoods);
}
```

*Code in controller, when update method is call only for first row in table:*

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload_shoe_image", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView handleFileUpload1(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
...
    try {
        ShoeGoods shoeGoods =  shoeGoodsService.getById(goodsId);

        shoeGoods.setImage(file.getBytes());

        //not call always
        shoeGoodsService.update(shoeGoods);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
...
}
```

*In JSP:*

```
 <form id="send-image-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
       action="/upload_shoe_image">
       Edit: <input type="file" name="file">
       <br />
       Save: <input type="submit" id="save-image" value="Upload">
 </form>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any error? Also why do you have `@ResponseBody` annotation? Are you doing a plain form submit or anything via ajax?

Comment: No errors, I send id choosen goods by json and use @ResponseBody

Comment: Hard to believe there would be _"no errors"_ (this is most likely caused by the fact that you're swallowing `Exception` and only printing to strerr: use proper logger instead or, preferably, don't catch exception if you're not intending to do anything about it), but you can always use your IDE's debugger to step through program flow line by line. You are the only one who can diagnose this, your question doesn't contain all the needed info.

Comment: kryger, I also don't believe what it's may be the problem... 3 hour don't finding her..